# how to get tasks that have a due date from task lists in nodejs Google Tasks API?

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

in [this](https://developers.google.com/tasks/quickstart/nodejs) page there is a nodejs example to get all task lists from Google Tasks. I get it to work and I've been playing around to get the tasks of each task list that have a due date, but i haven't even been able to get all tasks associated to a task list. Is it possible? It should be possible, but how?

I must say that i'm a beginner in nodejs... This is the example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete credentials.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks.readonly'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'credentials.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Slides API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listTaskLists);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the user's first 10 task lists.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listTaskLists(auth) {
  const service = google.tasks({version: 'v1', auth});
  service.tasklists.list({
    maxResults: 10,
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const taskLists = res.data.items;
    if (taskLists) {
      console.log('Task lists:');
      taskLists.forEach((taskList) => {
        console.log(`${taskList.title} (${taskList.id})`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No task lists found.');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: use service.task.get() I couldn't find any documentation for node.js, but I know thats the method.

Answer (score 1):

In the example, to get all tasks list from Google Tasks, you are using the function `service.tasklists.list`.

Then you need to get the id from every tasklist returned and call the function `service.tasks.list` with id from tasklists as parameter. Something like:

```
function getTasksFromTaskList(tasklistid, auth) {
  const service = google.tasks({version: 'v1', auth});
  service.tasks.list({
    tasklist: tasklistid,
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const tasks = res.data.items;
    if (tasks) {
      console.log(`Tasks from ${tasklistid}:`);
      tasks.forEach((task) => {
        console.log(`${task.title} (${task.id})`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No tasks found.');
    }
  });
}
```

You will find more information in the API reference: https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/list.

As you can see on that link, you can include more optional parameters in the request (for example, due date).

Comment: thanks!!!, i'm a little busy right now with work, but as soon as ia have time i wiil heck it out